# Реализация перекладывания одного стека в другой

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

Уже задавал вопрос о том, как переложить один стек в другой, исключая повторяющиеся элементы, но у меня это не получается это реализовать. Вроде все нормально, но программа падает на определённом шаге. Подскажите,что не так?

UPD:

```
for (int i = 0; i < curSize; ++i) func(stOne, stTwo, curSize, i);
```

где

```
void func(myStack <string> &stOne, myStack <string> &stTwo, int &curSize, int n)
{
    string compTmp,tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < curSize; ++i)
    {
        tmp = stOne.pop();
        if ( i == n ) 
            {
                compTmp = tmp;
                stTwo.push(tmp);
            }
        else if ( i < n ) 
            stTwo.push(tmp);
        else if ( i > n )
            if ( compTmp.compare(tmp) != 0 ) 
                stTwo.push(tmp);
            else curSize--;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < curSize; ++i) stOne.push(stTwo.pop());
}
```

Comment: Ваша проблема — чересчур большая сложность кода. Разбейте его на маленькие функции с говорящими за себя названиями, станет существенно проще.

Comment: @VladD А что тут можно разбить-то? Я пока вижу только объединение двух кусков кода в одну функцию, да и всё ;(

Comment: Например: я не понял смысл кода `if ((i % 2 == 0 ) && ( i > 0 )) index++;` Это значит, что его (или только проверку) надо отделить в функцию и дать ей осмысленное имя.

Comment: И у вас дикая глубина вложенности конструкций, а это означает, что функция делает слишком много мелкой работы.

Comment: @VladD ну, проверка означает, что мы будет брать за элемент сравнения элементы : 1,1,2,2,3,3.... Ведь так же нужно делать?
А функцию сейчас перепишу.

Comment: Брать за элемент сравнения? Ничего не понял.

Comment: А ещё непонятно часто встречающееся условие `i % 2 == 0`. Если это вы в один for пытаетесь запихнуть прямой и обратный ход перекладывания, не делайте так. Сделайте честно: внешний цикл пусть вызывает две функции: прямого перекладывания, а за ней обратного. Потому что иначе смысл переменной цикла отсутствует. А переменные без чёткого смысла — источник багов.

Comment: То есть конструкцию `if ((i % 2 == 0 ) && ( i > 0 )) index++;` надо не переделать, а просто искоренить.

Comment: @VladD понял. Это все от того,что я действительно захотел засунуть прямой и обратный ход в один цикл ;( Сейчас понимаю, что это было глупо.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Это стандартная ошибка — оптимизация там, где не нужно. Сэкономили одну переменную, потеряли читаемость и отлаживаемость программы.

Comment: @VladD Обновил код, пока он еще убогий и не работает для всех случаев ( типа 1 2 1 2 1 2 ) , но он хоть стал короче. Подскажите, в какую сторону пилить сейчас?)

Comment: @kvendingoldo: О, так намного понятнее. Для начала стоит переименовать переменные. `n` в функции — это что? Посмотрю код повнимательнее. PS: И ещё, что такое `cursize`? Это размер стека? Тогда его можно загнать в класс `myStack`, это ж по идее его свойство, текущий размер.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Ну вроде бы на первый взгляд правильно. А на каких данных не работает? (Чтобы можно было протестировать, выложите ещё `class myStack` на http://pastebin.com, ладно?)

Comment: @VladD например на ` 1 1 1 1 1 ` или же на ` 1 2 2 2 2 2 ` и тд.
`cursize`, действительно, должен быть методом класса, сейчас допишу его.

Comment: @VladD `n`  - номер элемента сверху, который мы берём для проверки на данный момент.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Отлично, а как он называется? `n`. Непорядок. Переименуйте в `currentCheckedIndex` или там `sizeOfCheckedPart`.

Comment: @kvendingoldo Не нужно выполнять декремент `curSize` - из-за этого не будет полностью "вычитан" `stOne`. И, кстати, проверка `i > n` лишняя (т.к. до этого уже были проверки `i == n` и `i < n`).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется стоит это сделать попроще, например сохранять элементы в векторе и таким образом проверять уникальность

```
void f(std::stack<std::string>& a, std::stack<std::string>& b)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string &item = a.top();
        a.pop();
        if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), item) != v.end())
        {
            v.push_back(item);
            b.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По условию, дополнительными структурами данных пользоваться нельзя.

Comment: И если уж запоминать элементы, то в `std::unordered_set`, у него поиск быстрый.